# jQuery's scroll function not working accurately

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, scroll

I wasn't sure what to make of the title for this problem, as it is quite complicated. To demonstrate, I've created a fiddle:

http://jsfiddle.net/2W5Jd/

Basically, I'm making a website containing different sections with different background colors. The designer thought it would be a good idea to change the color of the logo when you scroll down to another section, as if the section is "masking" the logo (see fiddle, it's hard to explain).

The problem however, as you can see in the fiddle, is that when you scroll fast enough, the logo stops resizing. Does anyone have any idea how to work around this?

---

As posting a link to jsfiddle.net must be accompanied by code, here's the js (I've simplified it a bit from the actual website version):

```
var $logo = $("#logo");

$(window).scroll(function(){
    scrollTop = $(document).scrollTop();
    $logo.css("top", scrollTop + "px");

    if ( scrollTop + 180 >=  600  ) {
        $logo.find(".second").css("height", (scrollTop + 180) - 600 + "px");
    }

});
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

add an `else` clause to your `if`

```
else {
        $logo.find(".second").css("height", (scrollTop + 180) - 600 + "px");
     }
```

see update fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/hbrunar/2W5Jd/1/

if you don't need to do anything else in the `if` part, then skip it completely:

http://jsfiddle.net/hbrunar/2W5Jd/2/